# Windows Azure Active Directory remove/transfer tenant domain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I joined to Windows Azure Active Directory beta trial when http://activedirectory.windowsazure.com was initially launched.

At initial process, site forced me to use a new LIVE account instead of the one I already have which is **myname@live.com** and also controls all my Azure services.  Anyway, I did create a new one as **myname@mycompany.com**

Next, I did be able to create the active directory domain as **mycompany@onmicrosoft.com** and added my **mycompany.com** domain as secondary domain.

While ago, Active Directory tab appeared in Azure control panel and it came empty.  So I assumed it needs to be link somehow but couldn't find anything about it.

After that, I tried to create a new domain but when I type **mycompany** into the *name* field of the *create a directory* page, it says *"This domain is not unique"* which is predictable since other live account holds the name.

Tried to delete entire account but didn't work.  Also in [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/en-us/jj151817#bkmk_remove) says :

> "The original contoso.onmicrosoft.com domain name that was provided for your tenant when you signed up cannot be removed from your tenant."

Since I'm the owner of the both account, I would like to move (or re-create etc.) **mycompany@onmicrosoft.com** under my actual Azure account which is **myname@live.com**.

Please advise.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't realize you had an existing subscription you were looking to work wit. So what you are seeing is expected behavior as there is no subscription associated with your Azure AD account.

We are propping an update this weekend and Monday that will help you here. On Tuesday morning, do the following:

1. Log into Azure using your Azure AD account.
2. It will tell you that you have no subscription - set up a 90 day trial subscription - you will not be charged anything for this.
3. Click onto Active Directory tab in the Azure Portal.
4. Add a new user - and select to add a user with a Microsoft Account - specify the account that is the administrator of your Windows Azure subscription and make them a "global administrator".
5. Log off
6. Log in to Azure portal using the same Microsoft Account that you just added.
7. Go into Settings.
8. Click on administrators tab
9. Select your Azure Subscription
10. Click "add" in the tray at the bottom
11. Now add the Azure AD user account you would like to have be a co-admin on your Azure subscription.

That should do it.  Now when you log in using your Windows Azure Account you'll be able to administer your Azure subscription.

Just a reminder - try this on Tuesday morning! We will have the update propped by then.

You can make this work though by creating a new 90 trial subscription - you do this on the page where you are being told there are no subscriptions associated with your account.

Comment: worked like a charm.  Thank you!  By the way, it looks like steps between 6 to 11 are not needed unless I want to continue to use Azure trial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into Azure using your myname@mycompany.com account (the Windows Azure Active directory account you created).

To do that, go to the Azure Management portal - if you are already logged in using a Microsoft Account (formerly LiveID) you will need to log-out first - Then the left hand side of the login page you should see a link that says "Office 365 users: Sign in using your organizational account".

Click on that link, and now log into the Azure portal using your Azure AD Account (myname@mycompany.com).  Once you do that, you should see your Windows Azure AD tenant in the Active Directory tab in the portal.

Comment: Thanks @alex-simons unfortunately it shouldn't work due to my MSDN subscription is registered on Microsoft Account.  What I want to do is either be able to transfer the ownership to my "Microsoft Account" or be able to re-create mycompany@onmicrosoft.com on my Microsoft Account.  By the way, I just tested what you suggested to make sure it doesn't work and it says "we were unable to find any subscriptions associated with your account" as I expected.  Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Comment: I also tried to add myname@mycompany.com as an co-admin into my subscription which is linked to my Microsoft Account but it says "This e-mail you provided is not a valid Microsoft account or organizational account"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)